# Concrete material: weird patterns appear in the final render

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, photorealism, pbr

I'm currently working on these renders of a bathroom. There is supposed to be concrete on the walls and in the final render these weird patterns appear and I don't know how to get rid of them. The material is from Megascans, it looks exactly as I need in the thumbnails. I checked the albedo picture and there are no patterns on it, just in the final render. I tried 4k and 8k versions but the problem remains. I was also messing with a bump, but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Could you please help me? Thank you for your reply.
[image: Final picture]

[image: Detail of a problem]

[image: Material nodes]

[image: UV]

Comment: Ah! Are you using these settings?
Cycles Render -> Experimental,
Adaptive Subdivision on the wall mesh,
Bump + Displacement enabled in the Material Properties of the wall material,


If not, enable them. Try that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried Adaptive subdivision and bump + displacement, and then everything in render turned black, so I disconnected displacement and it stopped doing these weird patterns, so I think I will render it without displacement. Otherwise, I'm using all the settings you mentioned.

Comment: Sounds good. Also, one more thing @Tomas: I'd recommend staying away from using displacement and using bump/normal map node-setups instead. Displacement only really looks cool when you are really close to that object. For example, let's say I am rendering a brick wall. From a distance, that brick wall would look real because I am using a normal map. However, when I get really close to it, it looks fake because it is flat. If I was doing a close-up of the wall, I'd use displacement. If I used displacement for that brick wall when I am far away, It would barely look better than a normal map! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your advicies. I just wanted to try displacement in hope there is gonna be some difference and it will make the material look more realistic, but as you mentioned its not important if its not closeup shot.